# Python Import in if performance

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know normally you should descripe your question the best you can. But now im just wondering if this code has better performance than `import module` on top of the code, because maybe its not in use.

```
a = 1
b = int(input()) # Input for testing
if b - a == 1:
    import Module 
    # use module
```

What about Not builtin librarys?

Cheers.

Comment: Sure, *not importing* things you don't use probably has a slight performance advantage over importing it. However, that advantage is entirely negligible for most built-in modules, and your code *does* require `time` to be imported or else it'll raise an error.

Comment: FWIW, low-level builtin modules like ``time`` are very likely to be *loaded* into the interpreter anyway, even if your specific module does not *import* it. Whether you import a loaded module or not has little performance impact.

Comment: The situations where you want to defer importing a module are pretty rare, and this is absolutely not one of them.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (condition):
    import module
else:
   pass
module.foo()
```

This will raise an exception when the condition is `False`, because at `module.foo()` the `module` won't be defined.

---

What's more writing

```
else:
    pass
```

is completely useless, since an `if` statement doesn't need an `else`.

---

Probably you were asking something like:

> Has not importing things you don't use a performance advantage over importing it?

In this case the answer is **YES**, but if your code doesn't need a very fast performance, I would suggest to simply import it even if you're not sure if you'll use it.